# How to use constants in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]Hi I am developing my first angularjs application. I want to define urls in file and make use of those urls throughout the application. I tried as below.

Constants.js

```
angular.module('RoslpApp').constant('cfg', {
    url: 'https://myapi.com/v1/'

})
```

I want to use it here.

```
function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('MainRegistration', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, cfg) {
        alert(cfg.url);
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('ForgotPassword');
        $translate.refresh();
        $translate.use('de_AR');
    }]);
})();
```

Currently I am getting Cannot read property 'url' of undefined Error. [image: My folder structure]

I want to make use of constants in all controllers inside Registration folder. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your injection should be like this, you are missing constant **`cfg`**,

```
  angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('MainRegistration', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate','cfg', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, cfg) {
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.  So whenever I want to inject something to controller i should use above format right?

Comment: Yes i am marking. But i can mark only after 10 mins. See the attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your help.